# React: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

been battling with this error for awhile, can't seem to figure it out. I have read over several other similar errors other people have had - seems to be pretty common but everyone has had a different solution.

`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Track from '../Track/Track';
import './TrackList.css';

class TrackList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="TrackList">
                {
                    this.props.tracks.map(track => {
                        return <Track key={track.id} track={track} />
                    })
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

    export default TrackList;
```

`

any ideas?

Comment: provide tracks data from the other component

Comment: Do a console.log(this.props) in your render method to see if tracks actually exists in props. And make sure to post your parent component .

Comment: solved it with ternary operator.. makes no sense to me but it works haha

Comment: Thanks everyone! :)

Comment: Well thats a quickest solution to use ternary operator. But make sure doing so doesnt break some other code. You are getting an undefined object in the initial go which is a potential issue to fix

Comment: in the future, try to provide a stack trace if you're reporting an error

Answer (score 2):

```
render() {
        const {tracks} = this.props;
        // if you are retrieving tracks from an API display a loader
        if (!tracks || tracks.length === 0) {
           return (<div>No tracks provided</div>)
        }

        return (
            <div className="TrackList">
                {
                    tracks.map(track => {
                        return <Track key={track.id} track={track} />
                    })
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like tracks is undefined, meaning there is no property called "tracks". Make sure you set a tracks property.

Comment: create instance of TrackList?

Comment: not an instance, but the parent component code where they're rendering TrackList